An app in C to create reservations for a meeting room, with three menu options
Please help refactor this code. I am a beginner at C, and want to learn clean code and best practices. This is an app with which:

users can make reservations (year, month, day, company name)
reservations are stored in a structure
if a date is not available user is notified
the structure of reservations are updated with a custom sorting mechanism

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_RESERVATIONS 100

// Structure for a reservation
typedef struct
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    char companyName[50];
} Reservation;

// Global variables
Reservation reservations[MAX_RESERVATIONS];
int reservationCount = 0;

// Function declarations
void showMenu();
void handleInput(int option);
void addReservation();
void inputReservation(Reservation *newReservation);
int isDateAvailable(int year, int month, int day);
void insertReservation(Reservation newReservation);
void printReservations();

// Main function - streamlined and clean
int main()
{
    int option;

    while (1)
    {
        showMenu();
        if (scanf("%d", &option) != 1 || option == 3)
        {
            printf("Exiting program.\n");
            break; // Exit the program
        }
        handleInput(option); // Delegate responsibility to handle user input
    }

    return 0;
}

// Show menu options
void showMenu()
{
    printf("\nMenu:\n");
    printf("1. New Reservation\n");
    printf("2. Print Reservations\n");
    printf("3. Exit\n");
    printf("Choose an option: ");
}

// Handle user input
void handleInput(int option)
{
    if (option == 1)
    {
        addReservation();
    }
    else if (option == 2)
    {
        printReservations();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
    }
}

// Add a new reservation (modular: only handles adding)
void addReservation()
{
    Reservation newReservation;

    // Input reservation details
    inputReservation(&newReservation);

    // Check if the date is available
    if (!isDateAvailable(newReservation.year, newReservation.month, newReservation.day))
    {
        printf("The room is already booked on that date.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Insert the reservation
    insertReservation(newReservation);
    printf("Reservation added successfully.\n");
}

// Input reservation details (year, month, day, company name)
void inputReservation(Reservation *newReservation)
{
    // Input: Date
    printf("Enter the reservation date (YYYY MM DD): ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &newReservation->year, &newReservation->month, &newReservation->day);

    // Input: Company name
    printf("Enter the company name: ");
    scanf("%s", newReservation->companyName);
}

// Check if the date is available for booking
int isDateAvailable(int year, int month, int day)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reservationCount; i++)
    {
        if (reservations[i].year == year &&
            reservations[i].month == month &&
            reservations[i].day == day)
        {
            return 0; // Date is not available
        }
    }
    return 1; // Date is available
}

// Insert the reservation in the correct position (sorted by date)
void insertReservation(Reservation newReservation)
{
    int i = reservationCount - 1;

    // Find the correct position and shift the elements back
    while (i >= 0 && (reservations[i].year > newReservation.year ||
                      (reservations[i].year == newReservation.year && reservations[i].month > newReservation.month) ||
                      (reservations[i].year == newReservation.year && reservations[i].month == newReservation.month && reservations[i].day > newReservation.day)))
    {
        reservations[i + 1] = reservations[i];
        i--;
    }

    // Insert the new reservation
    reservations[i + 1] = newReservation;
    reservationCount++;
}

// Print all reservations
void printReservations()
{
    if (reservationCount == 0)
    {
        printf("No reservations found.\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Current reservations:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < reservationCount; i++)
    {
        printf("%d-%02d-%02d: %s\n", reservations[i].year, reservations[i].month, reservations[i].day, reservations[i].companyName);
    }
}



To cover some points not yet fully explored:
User input
Code like scanf("%s", newReservation->companyName); has at least 4 problems.

No width limit, so the destination buffer may overflow.

Company names often have spaces in them and "%s" does not support that.

"%s" first consumes optional leading white-space, which may include '\n' rendering OP's line input amiss.

Code fails to check the scanf() return value for success here and in other scanf() calls.


Better to research fgets() to read a line of user input into a string and then parse the string.
Max reservation count not tested.
reservations[i + 1] = newReservation; may overflow.
Sometimes a comment is just noise
The comment here is superfluous.  Code is already using good object and function names.
// Insert the reservation
insertReservation(newReservation);
printf("Reservation added successfully.\n");

Better to declare with void
void showMenu(); will match a call like showMenu(1,2,3); as there is no argument checking.
Better to declare as void showMenu(void);.
This issue is likely moot with C2X.
Flush when done
User output, especially lacking a final '\n', deserves a following fflush(stdout) to insure output occurs before input.
Avoid copying large structures
void insertReservation(Reservation newReservation) copies the calling code's Reservation to newReservation.  Consider passing the address of the structure instead.
// void insertReservation(Reservation newReservation)
void insertReservation(const Reservation *newReservation)

Then later:
// reservations[i + 1] = newReservation
reservations[i + 1] = *newReservation

Input validation
Date input is fought with mistakes.  Consider validating the date to prevent reserving Sept 31, 2024.
Even the company name deserve some validation.

Thank you chux, I am implementing the insight and refactoring the code.

Immediate notes:

Try to avoid global variables. You can pass an array of reservations to each function to make debugging easier and to make your code more flexible. For instance, doing this you could have more than one set of reservations.
Avoid magic numbers. You've done that with MAX_RESERVATIONS but not with the maximum length of a company's name in your struct. If you implement suggestions for avoiding buffer overflows, you want to be able to set the maximum length once and have the rest of your program just work.

I would also suggest you create a struct to represent dates and have a Date as a component of your reservation struct. E.g.
typedef struct Date {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
} Date;

You can now define a comparison function for dates. E.g.
int date_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    Date c = *(Date *)a;
    Date d = *(Date *)b;

    if (c.year > d.year) return 1;
    else if (c.year < d.year) return -1;
    else if (c.month > d.month) return 1;
    else if (c.month < d.month) return -1;
    else if (c.day > d.day) return 1;
    else if (c.day < d.day) return -1;
    else return 0;
}

This would streamline sorting reservations by date as you could now more readily leverage standard library tools like qsort.
There are improvements that could be made to this comparison function. They key is that by factoring this logic out into a function, we can make improvements to this without having to modify the rest of the program.
You'll also want to sanitize your inputs. Right now when you call scanf (except in main) you check neither the return code to ensure it successfully read in the data you expected, nor do you check that the values read in fall within reasonable boundaries. Never trust your user.
You may also wish to define a ReservationSet struct which can keep track of your array and how many elements are in it. This can help you to not have to separately pass around a count of reservations. Such a data structure might also be crafted using dynamic allocation (and reallocation) so that the number of reservations can grow and MAX_RESERVATIONS is unnecessary.

Thank you very much Chris!

Don't use the old int/0/1. Use the Boolean type, which is the default in every modern language. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    ...
    while (true)
    ...
}

bool isDateAvailable(int year, int month, int day)
{
    for (...)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            return false; // Date is not available
        }
    }
    return true; // Date is available
}


Thank you for your answer Nayuki! It is great to see the abstract structure you have shown. Do we use return true; in the int main(){ return false; }; instead of return 0?

The return value of main() is special because it follows the rules for exit(int). You should actually return EXIT_SUCCESS instead of 0. It is not a bool value.
